# How can I make sure main thread ends after all other threads ends?

Tags: haskell, concurrency

```
import Control.Concurrent
main = do
    forkIO $ putStrLn "123"
    forkIO $ putStrLn "456"
```

I have written the code above. But when I executed it, I always got `123` only. `456` is not printed. I guess it is because main thread ended before the other thread so the whole program just ended.

How can I prevent this? Any api can make sure main thread ended after all threads ended?

OS: OS X 10.8.3

compiler: ghc 7.4.2

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use the `async` library:

```
import Control.Concurrent.Async

main = do
    a1 <- async $ putStrLn "123"
    a2 <- async $ putStrLn "456"
    mapM_ wait [a1, a2]
```

This is equivalent to Daniel's solution, except with two slight advantages:

- It ensures that any exceptions raised in the forked threads get re-raised in the parent thread without causing a deadlock
- It's more convenient

Comment: 3) It is easy for someone coming from another language to understand. 'async' and 'wait' have easily understood English meanings.  On the other hand,  ">> putMvar done ()" and "takeMvar done" are incomprehensible.

Comment: or `concurrently (putStrLn "123") (putStrLn "456")`

Answer (score 9):

```
import Control.Concurrent
main = do
    done <- newEmptyMVar
    forkIO $ putStrLn "123" >> putMVar done ()
    forkIO $ putStrLn "456" >> putMVar done ()
    takeMVar done
    takeMVar done
    -- OR: replicateM_ 2 (takeMVar done)
```

Comment: Beware of issues with exceptions, though. If an exception prevents a child thread from calling `putMVar`, you'll get a `BlockedIndefinitelyOnMVar` in the main thread. You can use [`forkFinally`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Control-Concurrent.html#v:forkFinally) to ensure `putMVar` gets called.